# what is the simplest method of extracting a 2D map file from the scenario?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on USARSim/ROS control framework. I have been able to move robot using keyboard through ROS package. Now I want to generate a global map in 2D of the USARSim environment where the robot is moving.
**What is the prerequisite for map_saver utility to generate a 2D map?**
Can anyone please help me regarding this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93856/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-extracting-a-2d-map-file-from-the-scenario?/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [slam_gmapping tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData).

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-24**:
Hi Bill, thanks for your quick reply.
I have gone through the tutorial. But unable to extract the map from laser data stored in rosbag. Again to get full map of the environment  do I need to  drive the robot around the environment continuously?

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-24**:
I think, if I use a correct bag file, then also the map_saver utility must give us the map.pgm.

rosbag play basic_localization_stage.bag

rosrun map_server map_saver

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-10-28**:
I have noticed that no messages are published in the /lms200 topic. Moreover I have realized that the corresponding /tf node does not exist. I suspect it's another bug in USARSim/ROS but I haven't investigated further.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2013-10-29**:
kr1zz Hi, how you came to know that no messages are published in the /lms200 topic, can you specify the filename in usarsim_inf package where modification has to be done? By the way USARSim/ROS modified something take a look. http://sourceforge.net/p/usarsimros/code/ci/master/tree/usarsim_inf/.
I have posted another question here http://answers.ros.org/question/94671/error-in-creating-2d-global-map-of-the-environment/